# Enterprise DHCP server solution?

Tags: dhcp, ip-address, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

I have a network of about 1000 assorted devices, all of witch are running by static IP addressing.  Given the size of the network and the lapse of technical advice, the addressing scheme is in chaos and there are about 14 class C subnets.

I would like to convert over to DHCP and pull everyone over to a class A subnet, however I am on a serious budget of free.

Currently I believe ISC's DHCP server will work nicely, however I need suggestions on a good GUI or another DHCP implementation with GUI built-in.  Would anyone be able to make suggestions?

Comment: Don't say things like "class A" and "class C". These were deprecated 20 years ago and are no longer used. Also, why on earth do you need a GUI?!

Comment: Your biggest problem, other than the subnet classes thing, is that you're talking about 'enterprise DHCP' but you've not defined an actual problem. Just about any half-decent DHCP server should be able to cope with handing out 1000 IP addresses. There are some people on this site who would probably configure their phone to do that quite cheerfully. Despite being much more of a 'windows guy' than a '*nix guy' myself, I'd still ask if a gui was must-have... once you get things configured correctly you shouldn't need to do too much to the DHCP server(s) (you want redundancy right?) you set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While product recommendations are off-topic for ServerFault and I expect your question to be closed by the community in short order, I can offer two suggestions:

1. Limiting yourself to a GUI-based system is limiting your ability to implement the best solution for your situation. Perhaps a system with a GUI will work well, or perhaps not.
2. In spite of the above, Windows Server has a decent DHCP system that can include a failover DHCP server and handle all of your disparate subnetting needs.

**Horrible suggestion that I should be beaten for mentioning:** Webmin has an ISC DHCP plugin.

P.S. 1,000 hosts and 14 subnets isn't a big deal at all, so don't worry about something needing to be "Enterprise." Enterprise would be hundreds of thousands of hosts and thousands of subnets between public and private spaces, IPv4 and IPv6. =)

Comment: The Windows DHCP server is nice, but one _major_ gotcha: It requires Windows Server CAL's.

Comment: @pauska Good point! *mumblemumbleEVILEMPIREmumblemumble*

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into Windows server and see where that goes.